# Pentaho - Generate UUID based on input fields

Tags: pentaho, uuid

Is there a way to generate UUID in pentaho step using input fields?

Example:

```
Input: Name, Address.
Output: UUID = UUID(Name + Address)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a [user defined java class](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.2/Products/Data_Integration/Transformation_Step_Reference/User_Defined_Java_Class) and use a code similar to this:

```java
String input = "Some name" + "Some address";
byte[] serialized = input.getBytes("UTF8");
UUID yourId = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(serialized);
```

This will generate a deterministic UUID based on the given input you have.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up creating a User Define class as mentioned by you in comments, and it's working fine.

Comment: Is it possible to get back the original input value from the ID generated?

Comment: @wassim Only via brute force, with the problem that you might hit a different input string (a property all hash functions share).

Answer (score 1):

you can use **Add checkup step** of pentaho data integration, it will create a unique code for combination of fields.

Answer (score 0):

The `UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes()` generates MD5 UUIDs. SHA1 is preferred over MD5. You can create SHA1 UUIDs with `UuidCreator.getNameBasedSha1()`.

In this example, the variables `name` and `address` are concatenated to generate a SHA1 UUID:

```java
// Create a name based UUID
String name = "localhost";
String address = "127.0.0.1";
UUID uuid = UuidCreator.getNameBasedSha1(name + address);
```

In this other example, a custom name space called "network" is used along with `name` and `address`:

```java
// Create a custom namespace called 'network'
UUID namespace = UuidCreator.getNameBasedSha1("network"); 

// Create a name based UUID inside the 'network'
String name = "localhost";
String address = "127.0.0.1";
UUID uuid = UuidCreator.getNameBasedSha1(namespace, name + address);
```

Project page: https://github.com/f4b6a3/uuid-creator